# gradle jacoco could not find org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.8.5

Tags: gradle, groovy, jacoco, ivy, jacoco-plugin

This is most likely just a beginner Gradle users question but I can't seem to figure this out.

I am trying to just get the basic task of jacocoTestReport running for a multi-project build  for a Gradle project I've been handed.

In the root project build.gradle file we have:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
  jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.8.5'
  }
```

Under dependencies we have:

```
jacocoAgent files("${rootProject.rootDir}/path/to/jacoco/zip/file/jacoco-0.8.5.201910111838.zip")
```

This zip file **jacoco-0.8.5.201910111838.zip** contains:

- coverage
- doc
- lib

  - jacocoagent.jar
  - jacocoant.jar
  - jacococli.jar
  - org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5.201910111838.jar
  - org.jacoco.ant-0.8.5.201910111838.jar
  - org.jacoco.core-0.8.5.201910111838.jar
  - org.jacoco.report-0.8.5.201910111838.jar
- test
- index.html

> I haven't included the files in the other folders than lib for brevity.

In a dependencies.build.gradle file we have a reference to:

```
jacoco_agent : "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.5"
jacoco_ant : "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.8.5"
```

When running **./gradlew.bat tasks** I can see the under verification tasks **jacocoTestReport**

When I try to run ./gradlew.bat jacocoTestReport I get the following error:

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':myProject:jacocoTestReport'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':myProject:jacocoAnt'.
> > Could not find org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.8.5.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - file:/C:/the/folder/with/zipFile/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.5.jar
> > - file:/C:/the/folder/with/zipFile/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.5.jar
> > - file:/C:/a/folder/without/zipFile/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.5.jar
> > - file:/C:/a/folder/without/zipFile/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.5.jar
> > - file:/C:/the/folder/with/zipFile/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.5.jar
> > - file:/C:/another/folder/withOut/zipFile/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.5.jar
> > - file:/C:/another/folder/without/zipFile/org.jacoco.ant.jar
> > Required by:
> > project :myProject

This is quite a large Gradle file so as a Gradle beginner it's a lot to go through, I've found various references to this repositories setup:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
      artifactPattern 'file://' + rootProject.file('some/folder') + '/[organisation]/[module]-[revision](.[ext])'
      ...
    }
}
```

Which matches the zip file location.

If Gradle can find the zip file and use the jacocoAgent (which is inside the zip file as a jar) how come it can't use the ant jar from within the same zip file?

This is using Gradle wrapper with Gradle version 6.5 for a multi Java project application.